# I think this is a compiler error, this shouldn't be affecting my code but it is

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-11

I have this in my code in my main function.

```
{
    int buncha_ints[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
}
```

when its not there my program works fine, and when it is there my program doesn't work. My question is, shouldn't this have absolutely no affect? A new scope is opened and then closed right away. This array is allocated, initialized and then cleaned off the stack. This has to be a compiler error if this is affecting the rest of my program right?

That's really my question but if more specifics are requested, This is a fairly simple DirectX11 Win32 program. I'm just rendering 2 squares to screen and when I put the above code in it doesn't render anymore. I wasn't able to render a third square and after experimenting I found a couple of oddities that boil down to the problem above, whenever something more than 4 bytes was allocated, no matter where it was, even if it is never called, my program stops rendering. Which seems notable sense my target platform is 32-bit.

Comment: Right, it should have no visible effect in a **correct program**.

Comment: `when its not there my program works fine, and when it is there my program doesn't work`  All of the signs of a memory corruption bug.  All you're doing when you add and remove that line is move around the corruption bug to another area of your program.

Comment: And BTW, *leave that line in the program and fix the bug*.  Do not remove it, thinking that your program is fixed without that line.

Comment: Be aware that when execution leaves the statement block, the variable will disappear and no longer be available.

Comment: `I'm just rendering 2 squares`  There is no "just" in your description.  If you make the slightest of mistakes, i.e. overwrite an array bounds, use uninitialized variables, or some other bug that can cause corruption, you introduce "undefined behavior".

Comment: You have overlooked the difference between "works fine" and "appears to work fine".  Your program is solidly in the latter category, not the former.

Comment: The only way for us to state the exact reason for the error is to see your code.  Unfortunately, the problem is that if you're not experienced enough to look for these mistakes yourself, you won't find them (everything will look ok to you).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Of course fixing a problem like this is how Michael will get experience ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical sign of accessing wrong memory location. i.e. some where in some other part of your program you are doing a beyond range access. When you define that array you are just shifting your memory blocks around. Just simply use [valgrind](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/245425-valgrind-is-not-a-leak-checker) to check that.

Comment: The question is tagged "winapi," so presumably the OP is using MSVC.  Does Valgrind work in that environment?